# Magento 2.2.7 Pagination Block not being written to page on search results

Tags: pagination, magento2.2.7

Pagination works fine on other pages but when I do a search and the results are posted, in this case more than 20, there are no paging controls displayed at the bottom and the block hasn't been output onto the page `/catalogsearch/result/index/?product_list_dir=asc&q=electric+jack`.

So it's not a css thing and I can't tell where I should be looking. Fairly new to Magento so it's still confusing :)

Comment: Are you using custom theme?

Comment: Yes BS_Clickbuy